# jQuery Form Validator OnSuccess with Alertify not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify, jquery-form-validator

I am using [jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html) with [Alertify JS](https://alertifyjs.com/) and I am using below code to check if my form successfully validated or not.

```
onSuccess : function($form) {
  alertify.alert('a callback will be invoked on ok.').set('onok', function(closeEvent) { 
    return true;
  }); 
  return false; // Will stop the submission of the form
},
```

Here what I am trying to do is, if I press `OK` From `Alertify` then my form should be submitted.

But as of now, if I remove `return false;` then my `Alertify` not showing and my form gets submited.

I also tried to put `$('#my-form-id').submit()` inside `return true;` but yet its not working.

Basically I just want to show my `Alertify` before form gets submitted just to notify the user with my alert box. But it seems above things not working for me correctly.

Here is the [jQuery Form Validator configuration documentation](http://www.formvalidator.net/#configuration) which I have followed.

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please check your console in chrome

Comment: I have checked and I am not getting any error in console.

Comment: yes I just read your link of Alertify

Comment: you have to prevent you submit action. Bcz you submit action refreshing you page that`s why alert wont execute.. If you prevent submit then alert will get execute.. return false is also preventing you submit action

Comment: yes .. i tried to remove `return false` and also removed `return true` and put my form submit jquery code but its still not working.